# Manually link native libraries for React native project from terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm following the instructions for manual library linking on:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#manual-linking

It involves dragging and dropping the `.xcodeproj` project file onto the and several other drag-and-drop steps.

Is it possible to do this through the terminal instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with React [Native Package Manager](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm), or rnpm.

Once rnpm is installed, you can install all of your native libraries by running `rnpm link` or a  single dependency by running `rnpm link <name>`.

Comment: Thanks...is this equivalent to the manual linking instructions?  I'm working with a library that specifically suggests the manual process: https://github.com/elliottsj/react-native-healthkit

Comment: It looks like these docs were written before rnpm was released, so that may have been why he specified manually linking, but then again I have not tried this specific library so that is just an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to link libraries manually anymore when you makes your react native projects.

[rnpm](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm) was made for linking native libraries to natives automatically. 
And rnpm project is merged to React Native.

Therefore, use `react-native link <name>` or `rpm link <name>` after install react native packages. 
Or just use `react-native link`. It makes link all modules' libraries automatically.